# DRV8833 MJKDZ: LED of Pico and CRV8833 turns of when connecting motor

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a DRV8833 MJKDZ with 12 pins and I try to run a 2.5 - 6V motor with it, using PWM with a Pi Pico, and it also worked once and back then the only problem was that when there was too much load on the motor the LED on everything turned off as here.

But now, after changing nothing just leaving it in a corner for a month or so it doesn't works at all. The first thing that can happen is that the LEDs stay on but the Motor doesn't move at all or only vibrated minimally and if I try to start it by rotating it, it sometimes powers for half a second but then stops again. The second thing that can happen is, that the LEDs on the Pi Pico and on the DRV8833 just turns off and then back on as soon as I disconnect the motor.

Now I can power the motor by using the 5V from the Pi Pico that also runs into the GND and VCC from the DR8833.

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

P.S.:I am powering the DRV8833 using the 5V sys power from the Pi Pico and powering the Pi Pico form a USB Port of my PC and the J2 Jumper is connected, as it worked once.

https://mvdlande.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/drv8833-motor-driver-module/ This is the DRV8833 MJKDZ

The load only whats attached to it on the picture.
I don´t know what kind of motor I have as the label isn´t readable except for the 2.5 - 6v, but here is a picture:
[image]

Schematic(Not so great but should serve its purpose):[image: Schematic of the setup]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We won't all know what a DRV8833 is so it's a good idea to add a link to the **datasheet** (not an Amazon ad page) **in your question** rather than in the comments. Add in a schematic showing how everything's connected. Running a motor from the Pi seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Compare the stall current of the motor with the motor driver's output current ratings. (Add both these figures to the question). If you exceeded its rating you may have damaged it, so replace it and (with a current limited PSU) try again. Also read the driver's datasheet looking for ways to add overcurrent protection.

Comment: Exactly which "2.5 - 6V motor" do you have, and what is the mechanical load? Is this the 'DRV8833 MJKDZ'? https://mvdlande.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/drv8833-motor-driver-module/

Comment: Yes, that is the DRV8833 MJKDZ but I havent found a datasheet for it